# Moving position of stacked bar in ggplot2 R closer to the y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I am looking for assistance with some R code that I have written to produce a stacked bar graph. This is using the ggplot2 package. Here is my code:

```
Plot1 = ggplot(data = data1, aes(x= Main_Cat, y= Percentage,  fill= Sub_Cat)) + # don't change these
  geom_bar(position = position_stack(), stat="identity", width = 1) + # don't change these
  ggtitle("title") +  # title text 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=14, face = "bold")) +
  xlab("All Categories") + # x axis text
  ylab("Percentage (%)") + # y axis text
  geom_text(aes(label = Percentage), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 4.6) + # number labels on graph
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + # background colour
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + # axis colour
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(1,1)) + # change position of axis
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12, face = "bold", colour = "black"), 
        axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold", colour = "black")) + # axis settings
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FFFF00", "#98FB98", "#00BFFF", "#0000FF")) + #change colours
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line("white")) 


print(Plot1)
```

[Plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1GgC.png)

I want to shift the bar closer to the y-axis OR to move y-axis closer to the bar without changing the width of the bar itself.

Any advice?

Comment: Could you provide "data1" or a little subset of it to be able to play with your provided code?

Comment: please use this reference for producing the same http://t-redactyl.io/blog/2016/01/creating-plots-in-r-using-ggplot2-part-4-stacked-bar-plots.html

Comment: Hi @Dave, I created an example dataset to use with the following code: 


 Main_Cat = c("All")
    Sub_Cat = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
    Percentage = c(4, 5, 67, 24)
      
    data1 = data.frame(Main_Cat, Sub_Cat, Percentage)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things to think about here that you can use to basically get the plot how you want it to look.  Namely, I'd use the following to adjust the position of the y axis relative to the bar:

1. Know that the output of the saved image is related to both the resolution and aspect ratio of your graphics device.  In other words, if you adjust the size of your graphics window, you get a different plot.  This also spills over into `ggsave()` (or however you are saving your image).  You can control the output by adjusting the `height=` and `width=` right in the `ggsave()` function.
2. The `width=` of your `geom_bar`.  You've set it at `width=1` in your code, but you can use this to squish or expand your bar.  If you only have the one bar, feel free to go over 1, but if you have more than one bar, `width=1.5` would spill over into the next axis value... not sure if this is an issue for you, but if not it can be a janky way  of getting the bar closer.
3. The best way to get the bar closer will be to use the `expand=` argument of `scale_x_discrete()`.  You already have used this... kind of.  Check the documentation on the function, where it mentions you should be using the `expansion()` function to set `expand=`.  It works to set `expand=c(0,0)` to remove all expansion around your plot - which is why your y axis has no expansion - but the same does not hold true if you just pass a vector to the `expand=` argument.  You should set it to `expand=expansion()` and then within `expansion()` you need to pass either `mult=` or `add=`.

You can adjust how you want, but here's the code I used to create two examples below with your plot.

#### Setting the axis right next to the bar

```
# use the entire code you already posted, except change only the line below:
scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(add=c(0,0)))
print(Plot1)

# remember, important to set the width/height
ggsave('example_1.png', width=2.5,height=5)
```

(Sorry, the image is huge on this page, but you can resize...)

[image]

#### Add a little space (but just a little) between the axis and the bar

```
# same as before, but your line now reads something like
scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(add=c(0.6,0.5)))
print(Plot1)

ggsave('example_1.png', width=2.5,height=5)
```

[image]